# Change UILabel text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am fairly new to objective-C and XCode.
I am trying to update a text label on the screen,

I call a function `loadData` in `viewDidLoad`, which works fine. I am trying to print a string that was generated in the `loadData` function.
After that string is generated, I use:

```
self.MyLabel.text=string;
```

But does not update.
I am using `IBOutlet` as well, I think it might be related to different threads but I am not sure.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe your outlet is not connected?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating the label after the

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   // call another method before assigning to retrieve the string here.
   self.MyLabel.text=string;
}
```

Sometimes the way the `UIViewController` and `IB` setup will need you to set in after the `viewDidLoad`. Try `NSLog(@"%@", self.MyLabel)` at wherever you try to assign to see if its not null

Comment: I tried this way and it works perfectly fine, but I need to update it using a value that was generated by my loadData function.

Comment: what does you loadData do? then u can call loadData: before assigning to self.MyLabel. As everything in the view is load. You can call anything there.

Comment: loadData connects to server and stores some data, I verified that data with NSLog. I save everything to a global variable, verified that as well, but when i use that to set the text, does not show anything

Comment: Print out the NSString immedeatly before adding:  NSLog(@"text=%@", mytext);

Comment: if you can assign initially, the connection is correct. can u check the self.MyLabel exist at that point. loadData: comes from the same ViewController is assume?

Comment: yeah loadData is in same class but uses properties from another class

Comment: it might be that loadData is running async method and when you assign the value it does not exist yet. could not clarify more without more code from loadData: (and others)

Comment: `*operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
     {
         RKLogInfo(@"Load collection of oData: %@", mappingResult.array);
         for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
         {
             fan1=mappingResult.array[i];
             
             RKLogInfo(@"%@",fan1.userId);
             RKLogInfo(@"%@",fan1.liveName);
             RKLogInfo(@"%@",fan1.liveId);
             RKLogInfo(@"%@",fan1.nickName);
             RKLogInfo(@"%@",fan1.rigId);
             lName=fan1.liveName;
             NSLog(@"%@",lName);
             [self.liveName setText:lName];
             
             
        }`

Comment: Leaving the loadData function out
I want to call a function, change the value of a string, and then display that on the screen, I tried, Any changes that I make on the fixed string inside the function are not being used when I try to set text after calling that function in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is correct:

```
self.mylabel.text = @"Test";
```

So make sure, that the IBOutlet is correctly connected (filled grey circle).

Check also if the string contains the correct value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I checked that and I have the filled grey circle. If I try setting string directly in the viewDidLoad, it works fine, but when I try setting it after calling the loadData function with a value generated in that function, it does not work.

And I checked, correct value is being generated by my function

Comment: try to set it with after calling loadData but not with the generated NSString but with a fixed one: e.g @"test" If that works, then you have forgotton to retain your generated string (If you use non ARC)

Comment: It does work with a fixed string, I now have the property to retain the value.But still does not work.  Xcode warns me that result unused.I am using self.label.text=(@"something %@", object.name);

Comment: can you post: the property definition, the calculation and the assigment: probaly you are assigning the calculated string to something else (the warning is a hint that there is something wrong)

Comment: @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString* liveName; an object of Fans class is created, I use NSLog to print out fan.liveName, which works fine. now i just want to print out fan.liveName to the label on screen

Comment: hwo do you assign it? self.liveName = calctext; or _liveName = calctext?

Comment: Its actually more complicated then that, I am using RestKit to parse OData, which gives me a mapping result Array. I make the FanDetails(separate class) object equal to the mapped array. 
This mapping was made in accordance with the class properties, so when I try fan.liveName, displays correct result. I am using fan=mappedResult.array; which allows me to use fan.liveName

Comment: The mapping is fine, I can print out everything with NSLog in my loadData funtion